# How to get the value of a radio input which is by default checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I have a radio button inside a `.map` method and the first is checked `defaultChecked={index === 0}`, how do I get the value of the `option` here? without using plain javascript

```
const [optionData, setOptionData] = useState({})  

{variant.options.map((option, index) => {
  <input
                                  type="radio"
                                  name="variant-select"
                                  id="variant-select"
                                  className="focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0 focus:text-red-600 text-red-600 border-none -mt-1 cursor-pointer z-10"
                                  defaultChecked={index === 0}
                                  value={index}
                                  onClick={(e) => {
                                    setOptionData(option)                                     }
                                  }}
                                />
} }
```

Comment: Where do you want get  value of the option?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question. @Viet

Comment: `how do I get the value of the option here`. What is `here`?

Comment: here, I meant when it's by default checked

Comment: and when user clicks on a different radio button I can do this 
```onClick={(e) => {
     setOptionData(option) 
}
}}
```

Comment: Yes. Your code will work fine

Comment: yes, any idea how can I store the first ones value in state? like when it's not clicked or changed

Answer (score 0):

This syntax may help you:`function myFunction() { var x = document.getElementById("myRadio").value; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; }`

Comment: sorry buddy, is there any way I could do this with react?
Cause sometimes I ran into problems like document undefined.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about. Tell me more about your problem.

Comment: I would like to get the value of defaultChecked input without using any on click or on change listeners, that value I'll get, I want to store that in local state.